# YUI3 - create global variable for avoid using .use(...);

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3, yahoo-api

I successfully migrate my page from YUI2 to YUI3 and while upgrading I was using the dynamic library loading of YUI3 only including `yui-min.js` and using  `YUI().use(...)`
, but now I want to delete the local YUI2 JS's and add YUI3 locally.

I created a Global Variable `var Y = YUI().use('*',function(Y){});` and changed the `yui-min.js` to `yui-core-min.js` and added the libs that I want to use and it works well changing `Y instead YUI()`.

```
Y.use('datatable','datasource', function(Y){
    ...
    fcTable = new Y.DataTable(...);
});
```

but I want to know if I can only call the `Y.use(...)` the first time and only work with the Global `Y` variable like:

```
    ...
    fcTable = new Y.DataTable(...);
```

I think it may make the loading a litle faster, It is recomended?

Thanks 4 your time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `use()` for modules that aren't currently on the page is an asynchronous operation, you're setting up a race condition.  Ignoring that, it is possible, yes.

```
Y.use('datatable');
```

will make `Y.DataTable` globally available when the module resolves and is attached.  The only trouble is that you can't guarantee when that will be.  This is the reason for the `use()` callback.

If all the module dependencies are already on the page statically (in a <script>), `use()` will be synchronous, which would allow

```
Y.use('datatable');
var table = new Y.DataTable({ … });
```

But if you're including the module scripts on the page and calling `use('*')`, then there's no need to explicitly call `Y.use('datatable')` later, since `*` attaches everything.

Comment: Hi luke thanks for answering, I declare all import of the <script>'s from yui webpage, and declared var ´Y =YUI().use('*');` but when delete the `Y.use('datatable');` and try to declare the `var table = new Y.DataTable({ … });` throws the error `TypeError: undefined is not a function` Im using the core lib that didnt download sources and with Y.use() works well, and I can do 
`var dialog = new Y.Panel({`
`contentBox : Y.Node.create('<div id="dialog" />'),`

without Y.use(...), Its a litle werid.

Comment: Are you compiling your static <script> includes from http://yuilibrary.com/yui/configurator/ ? (see http://jsbin.com/3/ufitab/1/edit?html,javascript,live)

Comment: I looked at my <script>'s includes and got all of your example + more, but still didn't work :(, I inspected the Y vble on firebug and see a lot of Objects inside it but no DataTable,

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6986621/YUI/yui3_1.PNG
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6986621/YUI/yui3_2.PNG

What means that the dynamic="false" on the DataTable function() ?

Comment: Hi luke, Changing the var Y for var YOO, I don't know why :S but looks working :D, migrate seems complete I'll add now the YUI3 build locally and continue working with YUI3, I starting like it ^^ DataTables + DD works very well.

Thanks for your help.